# there is a anomaly when spring Consolidate mybatis

Tags: spring

When ran comcat,it is often tell me wrong,I found a lot of date,didn't find the reasons.Is there anybody can help me?Thank you very much!

```
2012-08-28 14:33:49,531 >> ERROR >> main >>  >> [org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader] : Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sqlSessionFactory' defined in class path resource [applicationContext.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.core.NestedIOException: Failed to parse mapping resource: 'class path resource [SqlMapConfig.xml]'; nested exception is java.lang.RuntimeException: Error parsing Mapper XML. Cause: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1455)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:519)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:294)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:225)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:591)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:918)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:469)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:383)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:283)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:111)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4705)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:799)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:779)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:601)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory(HostConfig.java:1079)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectories(HostConfig.java:1002)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:506)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.start(HostConfig.java:1317)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java:324)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:142)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1065)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.start(StandardHost.java:840)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1057)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.start(StandardEngine.java:463)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.start(StandardService.java:525)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.start(StandardServer.java:754)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:595)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:585)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:289)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:414)
Caused by: org.springframework.core.NestedIOException: Failed to parse mapping resource: 'class path resource [SqlMapConfig.xml]'; nested exception is java.lang.RuntimeException: Error parsing Mapper XML. Cause: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionFactoryBean.buildSqlSessionFactory(SqlSessionFactoryBean.java:412)
    at org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(SqlSessionFactoryBean.java:295)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1514)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1452)
    ... 36 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error parsing Mapper XML. Cause: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.ibatis.builder.xml.XMLMapperBuilder.configurationElement(XMLMapperBuilder.java:113)
    at org.apache.ibatis.builder.xml.XMLMapperBuilder.parse(XMLMapperBuilder.java:88)
    at org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionFactoryBean.buildSqlSessionFactory(SqlSessionFactoryBean.java:410)
    ... 39 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.ibatis.builder.xml.XMLMapperBuilder.configurationElement(XMLMapperBuilder.java:104)
    ... 41 more
```

Spring allocation

```
<bean id="sqlSessionFactory" class="org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="mapperLocations" value="classpath:SqlMapConfig.xml" />
    </bean>
```

SqlMapConfig.xml allocation

```
<typeAliases>
       <typeAlias type=" com.qtp.UniWebApFramework.dto.RoleDTO" alias="roleDTO"/>
    </typeAliases>
    <mappers>
        <mapper resource="roleMapper.xml"/>
    </mappers>
```

roleMapper.xml allocation

```
<mapper namespace="com.qtp.UniWebApFramework.dto.RoleDTO">
<resultMap type="roleDTO" id="roleMap">
<result property="roleID" column="F_ROLE_ID"/>
<result property="roleType" column="F_ROLE_TYPE"/>
<result property="roleName" column="F_ROLE_NAME"/>
<result property="createAreaID" column="F_CREATE_AREA_ID"/>
<result property="ifDefault" column="F_IF_DEFAULT"/>
<result property="dutyID" column="F_DUTY_ID"/>
<result property="creater" column="F_CREATER"/>
<result property="desc" column="F_DESC"/>
<result property="state" column="F_STATUS"/>
</resultMap>

    <select id="queryAll"  resultMap="roleMap">
        SELECT * FROM OM_ROLE_T
    </select>

</mapper>
```